# jetty servlet, can't hit @GET methods

Tags: jetty, jax-rs

normally figure stuff out but I've been stuck on this one for a couple days now..
building up a simple jetty server. the server runs, and localhost:8080 pulls up the right index.html file. but I'm trying to run a java back-end using @GET and @PATH annotations, but none of the paths I try seem to work. say I have the following:

```
@Resource
@Path("hello")
public class AjaxCalls{
    @PATH("sayHi")
    @GET
    public String test(){
        return "Hi";   //breakpoint set here to see if we hit the method
    }
}
```

I would think that an ajax call to the url: localhost:8080/hello/sayHi would at least hit the breakpoint, but no luck. Anyone take this approach before? I'm sure it's some small detail...

Comment: We'll need to see your Jetty server setup (assuming it's embedded), your dependencies/jars, and any JAX-RS related configuration you have.

Comment: Can you post your `web.xml` file?

Comment: Did you mean "jersey"? (not "jetty"?)

Comment: Please review the answer given below, thanks.

Comment: What's you Application class like? What's in @ApplicationPath ?

Answer (score 0):

One explanation for why you are not hitting the Jersey `@Get` method is because you are using the wrong URL.  Here is an example of a URL which *should* work assuming you also have the following setup:

```
http://localhost:8080/your-project-WAR/rest/hello/sayHi
```

This URL would hit the `@Get` method `test()` if the name of your WAR is `your-project-WAR.war`, and you had a `web.xml` looking something like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Your REST service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Your REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The Tomcat server consumes the `your-project-WAR` portion of the URL, and the `web.xml` file consumes the `/rest` potion before it forwards the rest to the Jersey framework.  As it stands now, the URL you are using is likely to be problematical because it appears to be missing so many things.  I hope that this answer can set you on the right path quickly.

Comment: thanks, sorry this is my first web app... my pom.xml (aside from dependencies) looks like this: 

        <groupId>example</groupId>
        <artifactId>server</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>root</name>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <jettyVersion>9.0.2.v20130417</jettyVersion>
        <build-support-version>1.4</build-support-version>
    </properties>

and i have a WAR root.war, but trying to GET from http://localhost:8080/root/rest/hello/sayHi still doesn't seem to work

Comment: What is the _exsct_ name of the WAR file after you build it?  Did you update your `web.xml` as I mentioned?